# SwiftUI Center VStack items in GeometryReader

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple tab view in which I am showing stack with items. But issue is item not showing in a centre list it's showing from start. I need to know how can I centre this I already tried with alignment in Vstack which is not working. I have found a solution to wrap it with Hstack and add spacer on both sides but I need some good way to do this.

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ proxy in
        let screenSize = proxy.size
        
        ZStack (alignment: .top){
            Color(hex: "#E8ECF4")
            tabHeader(size: screenSize)
            TabView(selection: $currentTab){
                ForEach(sampleTabs) {tab in
                    GeometryReader{ proxy in
                        VStack(alignment: .center){
                            matchCardView()
                                .frame(width: 376)
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 60)
                    }
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .offsetX{ value in
                        if currentTab == tab {
                            offset = value - (screenSize.width * CGFloat(indexOf(tab: tab)))
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(tab)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page (indexDisplayMode:.never))
            
        }
        .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .horizontal alignment on the VStack containing the item. However, since you mentioned that the alignment property didn't work for you, you can try using the Spacer view to center the content.

```
var body: some View {
GeometryReader { proxy in
    let screenSize = proxy.size
    
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        Color(hex: "#E8ECF4")
        tabHeader(size: screenSize)
        TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
            ForEach(sampleTabs) { tab in
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            matchCardView()
                                .frame(width: 376)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 60)
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .offsetX { value in
                    if currentTab == tab {
                        offset = value - (screenSize.width * CGFloat(indexOf(tab: tab)))
                    }
                }
                .tag(tab)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
    .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
}
```